# Counting occurrences of a string in multiple columns of a data frame

Tags: r

I've the following data frame and I want to count the occurrences of the word "High" for each rows and append as another column say "countHigh" to the data frame

```
     a    b    c
1 High High High
2 High  Low High
3  Low  Low High
```

So I should get a vector of counts (3,2,1).

I've tried apply() and stringr:str_count as follows:

```
> apply(test.df[,1:3],1,str_count,"High" )

    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    1    1    1
```

and I used the apply() function twice:

```
> apply(apply(test.df[,1:3],1,str_count,"High" ),2,sum)
[1] 3 2 1
```

Is there a better way to do this, particularly using apply() just once and using grep() or which() ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it a fixed string, then create a logical matrix with `==` and get the `rowSums` from `base R` (should be fast compared to `apply`)

```
test.df$countHigh <- rowSums(test.df == "High")
```